# Asynchronous state updates causing issues in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm currently facing an issue with my Jest tests where the asynchronous behaviour of setTimeout and await calls is causing problems with the order of execution. I have a test where I simulate a button press, but the handler for this button press is being called before another asynchronous function (usernameHandler) finishes executing.

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```js
// Component
useEffect(() => {
  const timeOutId = setTimeout(() => usernameHandler(username), 500);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeOutId);
}, [username]);

const usernameHandler = async (toCheck: string) => {
  const unique = await checkUniqueUsername(toCheck, user);
  setUsernameUnique(unique);
  setUniqueChecking(false);
};

const handleButtonPress = async () => {
  if (uniqueChecking) {
    setUsernameError(t("onboarding.username.loading"));
    return;
  }
  // Other logic...
};
```

And my test:

```js
// Test
jest.mock("../../utils/uniqueUsername", () => ({
  cacheUsername: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (username, user) => {
    if (username === "notUniqueButCached" && user === "mockUserId") return true;
    else return false;
  }),
  checkUniqueUsername: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (username, user) => {
    if (username === "unique" && user) return true;
    else return false;
  }),
}));

describe("SignUpEmailScreen", () => {
  it("should navigate when username is unique", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { getByTestId, findByTestId } = renderWithProviders(
      <OnboardingUsername route={mockRoute} navigation={navigation as any} />
    );
    fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId("username-input"), "unique");

    await waitFor(
      () => expect(getByTestId("next-button").props.disabled).toBe(false),
      {
        timeout: 1000, // time in ms
      }
    );

    fireEvent.press(getByTestId("next-button"));

    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("OnboardingAvatar", {
        user: "mockUserId",
        name: "John Doe",
        username: "unique",
      })
    );

    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
});
```

The log statements indicate that handleButtonPress is being called before usernameHandler finishes its execution. When handleButtonPress is called, uniqueChecking is still true because setUniqueChecking(false) in usernameHandler has not yet executed, causing the test to fail. I've tried using jest.useFakeTimers() and jest.runAllTimers() or jest.advanceTimersByTime(), but it seems that these only affect timers created with setTimeout, setInterval, etc., and don't affect the execution of promises (await calls).

How can I ensure that usernameHandler has finished executing before handleButtonPress is called in my Jest test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `expect(usernameHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()` You can use it to check that it has been called before.

Comment: I cannot check if usernameHandler has been Called, because I have no access to the function from my test case. The function does not get exported so there is no way i can listen to it, right?